# Translation of an article by Šapirovskiĭ

Tags: gn.general-topology, soft-question, paper-request

The AMS has a book, [Fourteen Papers Translated from the Russian](http://www.ams.org/books/trans2/134/), containing an article by Šapirovskiĭ, "Cardinal invariants in compact Hausdorff spaces", that I would very much like to consult, but I do not currently have the means to obtain a digital copy of the book in question. Please, do any of you have a copy of Šapirovskiĭ's article that you can perhaps share with me?

Comment: Many university libraries will have copies of these books (AMS translation series). Even finding the Russian original of this seems tricky (the original title is longer, and is in a conference proceedings).

Comment: The book is in the archive: https://archive.org/details/fourteenpaperstr0134unse/ but under a loan system which I do not know how it works.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That table of contents is for volume 136, not 134.

Comment: I have a scan of the article; uploading it here is probably not legit, but I presume that emailing it to you counts as "fair use"; just drop me a line and I will send it to you.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you very much! I will write to you right away.